# C# MemoryCache to store different data type

Tags: c#, memorycache, in-memory-cache

I'm using `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory`, as I hav read it is the newer implementation of `System.Runtime.Caching`.

I have been reading that it's not recommended to have more than one instances of `MemoryCache` along the application to take advantage of the memory management.

I need to store more than one type of elements in the Cache. Currently I'm using `tuples` as keys to locate items in cache. But maybe I need to use it on more classes.

I can do it using my IoC like `Autofac` to include it as a `Singleton` and maybe doing some interface to encapsulate the cache management.

I can use tuples to store key type and key, or avoid using tuples and creating a class to represent different type of keys implementing IEquatable.

```
public void AddItem(object key, object value){
    _memoryCache.Add((keyType: key.GetType().FullName, keyValue: key), value);
}
```

What is the best solution to store different type of items and get them also? It's true that it's not recommended to have more than one instance of MemoryCache? I'm searching for a good solution in terms of performance to get items as fast as possible.

Comment: MemoryCache is a wrapper around ConcurrentDictionary. I see no reason to limit ourselves to only one instance. That's ridiculous.

Comment: @freakish I have read in other posts that it was not recommended to have more instances. Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8463962/using-multiple-instances-of-memorycache

Comment: Honestly, this highly voted answer can be summed up as: multiple cache instances come with a minor memory overhead (obviously). As long as you remember that it is completely fine. And you can also read in the linked question that many, many people do that.